# Logstash - Split escape character " \ " is not working

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have logstash to check log from window file ; there is many app running on window show I think using the folder to determinate this log come from what app ; but it is not working  and get the exception :

> Failed to execute action
>   {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main,
>   :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of
>   \', ', any character at line 21, column 1 (byte 237)

my config

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
        mutate {
                split => { "source" =>  '\\' }
        }

}
output {
 elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    sniffing => true
    manage_template => false
    index => mt4log
  }
}
```

someone can help me find out what is  problem here thanks

Comment: I couldn't solve your problem directly, but a possible solution would be to first replace the `\` with another string, then do the split on that string.

Comment: To replace the \, you can use the mutate filter with the gsub option.